# Unlink iMessages between devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

How do I disable iMessage syncing between my iPhone and iPad? In other words, I do not want messages sent to my phone to display on my iPad and likewise. I don't want messages sent to my email to display on my iPhone.

Is there a way to unlink my phone number from iMessages on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

On your iphone go to Settings > Messages and turn off "text message forwarding".  Then scroll down and look for "Send and Receive" where you can control what addresses or phone numbers messages can be received using.

You may or may not want to turn Settings > Messages on the iPad off, I think the above two changes will handle what you are looking to accomplish.